# Gettin an error while trying to create a webelment object in selenium even with try block

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am making a small utility on selenium. In one of the functions, I'm trying to create a web element object with xpsth which probably doesn't exist, so I use a try block but I still get an error. I would like to know why this is happening and how can I fix it or is there any alternative way to implement this funk?
function:

```
for o in options:
    try:
        a = o.get_attribute("value")
        options_text.append(a)
    except:
        print("No value atribute")
    else:
        print("Done", options_text)
for e in options_text:
    to_select = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"//*[@value='{e}']")
    to_select.click()
    submit_btn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="id_submitbutton"]')
    submit_btn.click()
    try:
        agn_btn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Спробувати знову')]")
        agn_btn.click()
    except:
        cnt_btn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Продовжити')]")
        cnt_btn.click()
        break
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\WebDriver\main.py", line 84, in solve
    agn_btn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Спробувати знову')]")
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\WebDriver\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 831, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\WebDriver\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 440, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\WebDriver\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //*[contains(text(), 'Спробувати знову')]
Stacktrace:
RemoteError@chrome://remote/content/shared/RemoteError.sys.mjs:8:8
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:182:5
NoSuchElementError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:394:5
element.find/</<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/element.sys.mjs:134:16


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\WebDriver\main.py", line 99, in <module>
    solve(test)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\WebDriver\main.py", line 88, in solve
    cnt_btn.click()
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\WebDriver\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 94, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\WebDriver\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 403, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\WebDriver\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 440, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\WebDriver\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <title> could not be scrolled into view
Stacktrace:
RemoteError@chrome://remote/content/shared/RemoteError.sys.mjs:8:8
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:182:5
ElementNotInteractableError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:292:5
webdriverClickElement@chrome://remote/content/marionette/interaction.sys.mjs:150:11
interaction.clickElement@chrome://remote/content/marionette/interaction.sys.mjs:119:11
clickElement@chrome://remote/content/marionette/actors/MarionetteCommandsChild.sys.mjs:208:29
receiveMessage@chrome://remote/content/marionette/actors/MarionetteCommandsChild.sys.mjs:97:31


Process finished with exit code 1
```